# RestSharp 107.2.1 throws 'Request failed with status code UnsupportedMediaType'

Tags: restsharp

I'm trying to send a post request with RestSharp 107.2.1 and I receive the 'UnupportedMediaType' error.
Sending the same body as raw json and the same parameter with Postman is successful.

I tried to use the 'AddBody' and 'AddJsonBody' with and without serializing first with jsonconvert, all throws the same error. Any idea how to make this work?

```
            var udfbody = new
            {
                name = "testname",
                displayName = "testdisplayname",
                required = "False",
                type = "TEXT"
            };

            var addudf = new RestRequest();
            addudf.Resource = "addUserDefinedField";
            addudf.Method = Method.Post;
            addudf.AddHeader("Authorization", bamauthtoken);
            addudf.AddParameter("type", "IP4Network");

            //1
            //addudf.AddBody(udfbody, ContentType.Json); 

            //2
            //addudf.AddJsonBody(udfbody);

            var serializedbody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(udfbody);

            //3
            //addudf.AddJsonBody(serializedbody);

            //4
            //addudf.AddBody(serializedbody, ContentType.Json);

            //5
            addudf.AddParameter("application/json", serializedbody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var addudfresp = await restclient.PostAsync(addudf).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[here is an image about the same body in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvXqk.png)

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured out.

```
addudf.AddParameter("type", "IP4Network");
```

needs to be

```
addudf.AddQueryParameter("type", "IP4Network");
```

Comment: Indeed, when you used `AddParameter` for the POST request, the parameter was added to the request body, and the request was posted as multipart form data.

Comment: I learned the difference between 'AddParameter' and 'AddQueryParameter' the hard way. The nasty thing was the UnsupportedMediaType error message with this version of RestSharp. I figured out the problem when I rolled back to an old version of RestSharp which gave me a 'missing parameter' error.

Comment: It is not RestSharp that fails with that response code, it's your server. The difference between those methods is clearly (I hope) documented.